# How to update package-lock.json without doing npm install?

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

**Question**

What is the way to update/generate `package-lock.json` without making a real installation of `node_modules` (what `npm install` does)?

I want just a valid `package-lock.json` based on my `package.json`, that's it.

**Motivation**

You might use `yarn` locally, when CI server uses `npm`. It's probably not the best practice, but still might ok as a temporary solution.

**Bonus question**: Same for `yarn`. Is it possible to generate `yarn-lock.json` without doing a real installation?

Answer (score 243, accepted):

## npm

As of npm 6.x, you can use the following command:

```
npm i --package-lock-only
```

Documentation (https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install.html) says:

> The `--package-lock-only` argument will only update the `package-lock.json`, instead of checking node_modules and downloading dependencies.

## yarn

As of yarn 3.0.0, you can use the following command:

```
yarn install --mode update-lockfile
```

Documentation (https://yarnpkg.com/cli/install#options-mode%20%230) says:

> If the `--mode=<mode>` option is set, Yarn will change which artifacts are generated.
>
> `update-lockfile` will skip the link step altogether, and only fetch packages that are missing from the lockfile (or that have no associated checksums). This mode is typically used by tools like Renovate or Dependabot to keep a lockfile up-to-date without incurring the full install cost.

<s>**As of Sep. 10, 2019:** yarn doesn't seem to support generating a lock-file without installing the modules. Relevant GitHub issue: https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/5738</s>

Comment: The lock file must be deleted first. Is there any one command solution without the need to delete the lock file first?

Comment: I have to mention that sometimes package-lock.json might be slightly different from what you got in case you do a normal npm install

Comment: Yeah, the trouble is it STILL doesn't seem to update transitives, like you might be expecting. It doesn't really update anything from the existing lockfile, although it will repair deleted things.

Answer (score 6):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, so just add an answer :)

In addition to [Teh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4269798/)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57867531/7011476), for Yarn now you can:

```
yarn install --mode update-lockfile
```

Documentation: https://yarnpkg.com/cli/install#options-mode%20%230

> `update-lockfile` will skip the link step altogether, and only fetch packages that are missing from the lockfile (or that have no associated checksums). This mode is typically used by tools like Renovate or Dependabot to keep a lockfile up-to-date without incurring the full install cost.